# Как построить модель векторной авторегрессии (VAR модель)?

Tags: математика, r, статистика, анализ-данных, статический-анализ

Необходимо оценить реакцию одной переменной на шок другой (с помощью векторной авторегрессии).
Учитывая специфику рядов возникли следующие вопросы:

1. При при проверке на наличие единичного корня (ADF-test) для одного из рядов по информационному критерию Акайка лучшей оказалась модель с 4 лагами (ряд стационарный, вероятность принятия 0 гипотезы около 3%), по критерию Шварца с лагом 3 (ряд нестационарный, вероятность принятия 0 гипотезы о наличии единичного корня примерно равна 50%). Как правильно тогда интерпретировать результат, если при изменении количества лагов в модели авторегрессии наблюдается такое различие в результатах? Можно ли считать ряд стационарным при уровне значимости 5%?
   Если в дальнейшем используется VAR c лагом 3, то и ADF-test необходимо рассматривать с 3 лагами ( вне зависимости от информационных критериев).
2. Второй ряд (в уровнях) является нестационарным, взятие первых разностей свидетельствует о том, что он интегрированный 1-го порядка. Правильно ли я понимаю, что порядок определяется по минимальной разности уровней, то есть стационарность вторых разностей ни на что не влияет?
3. Требуется ли, что оба входящие в VAR модель ряда были стационарными? Вроде нигде такого жесткого требования не звучит, но меня немного смущает, то что оценка проводится метод OLS, условием которого является стационарность всех рядов во избежании ложной регрессии.
4. Если подобрать необходимое количество лагов для того, чтоб обе переменные стали интегрированными первого порядка, при проведении теста Йохансена, обнаруживается 1(в некоторых моделях 2) коинтегрирующих вектора? В данных условиях можно использовать VAR моделью, если ряд короткий и основной упор делается на анализе краткосрочной реакции.
   Еще несколько спорных пунктов (для новичка) по самой методологии теста на наличии коинтеграции:

- Тест проводится на непреобразованных (сырых) рядах?
- Если количество лагов в VAR или VECM - n, то количество лагов в тесте n-1? Например в VAR (1 5), здесь пишем (1 4)?

5. Если нет возможности избежать в данном случае построение модели векторной коррекции ошибок (VECM) и у нас отсутствуют какие-то априорные предположения необходимо ли ставить какие-то ограничения на коэффициенты? Каким образом можно построить вектор данных ограничений? Будет ли отличаться интерпретация функции импульсных откликов в данном случае (тут же анализируются краткосрочной отклонения) и как вообще можно в этой модели отделить краткосрочную динамику от долгосрочной?VECM строится на уровнях (сырых рядах) или разностях переменных?
6. При построение VAR существуют ли ограничения на взятие одного из рядов в уровнях, а другого в разностях? Конечно, это усложняет интерпретацию результатов, но есть ли жесткие запреты со стороны математики? Это касается и использования интегрированных рядов разного ненулевого порядка.
7. Принято выбирать модели по информационным критериям, какие есть условия обхода этого требования (то есть одна из моделей выглядит и логичнее и человечнее, но формально доказать ее использования, пока нет возможности).
8. Результаты теста Грейнджера также существенно разнятся при выборе разного количества лагов. При этом в большинстве случаев обнаруживается причинность в обоих направлениях? Это значит, что необходимо найти 3 фактор, который влияет на первые 2, или это можно рассматривать, как свидетельство коинтегрированности и необходимости построение VECM?
9. В чем принципиальное отличие функции импульсного отклика от накопленного импульсного отклика? В каких случаях предпочтительнее применить каждую из функций?
10. Минимальное количество тестов, которые свидетельствуют об адекватности модели VAR? (кроме самых простых оценка значимости коэффициентов в уравнении и коэффициента детерминации, информационных критериев, стандартных статистик остатков (гетероскедастичность и автокорелляция), удовлетворяет ли многомерный временной ряд условию устойчивости, т.е. является ли слабостационарным многомерным процессом, а также гипотезу о значимости запаздывающих значений эндогенных переменных.
    Буду благодарна, если кто-то вообще сможет на человеческом языке четко описать алгоритм действий при оценке? Или подскажет, где можно найти ответы на поставленные вопросы.
    Использовала пока Eviews Help, соответственно различные туториалы к нему, а также учебники эконометрики Носко В.П. и Доугерти.

Comment: Ух, сколько вопросов сразу. Будет лучше, если Вы создадите много отдельных вопросов. В таком виде его, скорее всего, закроют.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подсказку) попробую преподнести сие творение в разбавленном виде.